# Наследование JavaScript6

Tags: ecmascript-6, extend

Мне нужно создать объект Orc

```
class Orc extends new Entity(){
constructor(){
    super();

    this.lifetime = 100;
    this.move_x = 0;
    this.move_y = -1;
    this.speed = 1;
}}
```

Который наследуется от класса Entity

```
class Entity{
constructor(){
   this.pos_x = 0;
   this.pos_y = 0;
   this.size_x = 0;
   this.size_y = 0;
}}
```

Когда я пытаюсь это сделать

```
let obj = null;
                obj = new Orc();
```

У меня вылетает исключение: 
Class extends value # < Entity > is not a constructor or null

Кто-нибудь помогите разобраться с этой проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `new` и скобочки лишние. Нужно так:

```
class Orc extends Entity {
constructor(){
    super();

    this.lifetime = 100;
    this.move_x = 0;
    this.move_y = -1;
    this.speed = 1;
}}
```